# XOR-like Select Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm having a bit of a brain cramp, and I'm not sure how to even word the question, so I'm going to do it by example...

I have a table, table_a, with some number of rows and I need to do a select based on 2 columns.  Basically I want to select a row if A and B are true.  However if B isn't true, I need to select the row where A is true and B is another value.

So given a table like this...

```
Col A    ColB
1        'X'
1        'Y'
2        'Z'
```

I want to say something like...

Give me all the rows where ColA='1' and ColB='X'.  If that doesn't exist, give me the rows where ColA='1' and ColB='Y'.  But I don't want (1,Y) if (1,X) exists.

Yikes.  How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: Can you use CASE statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE
  (ColA, ColB) = (SELECT ColA, ColB FROM yourtable WHERE (ColA, ColB)=(1,'X')
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT ColA, ColB FROM yourtable WHERE (ColA, ColB)=(1,'Y')
                  ORDER BY (ColA, ColB)=(1,'X') DESC
                  LIMIT 1)
```

Subquery will return either (1, 'X') if there's at least one row that has `ColA=1` and `ColB='X'`, otherwise it will return `(1,'Y')` if there's at least one row with such values.

In case they both are present, ordering by `(ColA, ColB)=(1,'X')` DESC and using `LIMIT 1` assures that the precedence is given to `(1, 'X')`.

Or this one that uses OR:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE
  ((ColA, ColB) = (1, 'Y')
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                  FROM yourtable
                  WHERE (ColA, ColB)=(1,'X')))
  OR
  ((ColA, ColB) = (1, 'X'))
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa81d/4).

Answer (score 0):

I would just use two separate queries to do this.  The first query would be `ColA = 1 AND colB = 'X'`.  If it does not return results, then the second query will run to acquire `(1, Y)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it just using a `LEFT JOIN` if I understood your requirements correctly.

```
SELECT T.ColA, T.ColB
FROM YourTable T
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ColA
    FROM yourtable T
    WHERE ColB = 'X'
    ) T2 ON 
      T.ColA = T2.ColA
WHERE T.ColB = 'X' OR T2.ColA IS NULL
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7088/1)

I was assuming if the same cola had multiple records, return the one with colb=X (if it exists).  Otherwise, return the row as is -- hence 2 Z in the results:

Results:

```
COLA   COLB
1      X
2      Z
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select T.colA,T.colB
from table T
where T.colA = ANY (select colA from table where colB != T.colB);
```